# Convertir fecha a mili segundos Angular

Tags: angular

Tengo un date en mi component.html

```
<input type="date"  class="form-control" ng-model = " myDate "  (change) = " updateMyDate ($event) ">
```

y realizo la función de obtener la fecha que selecciono en mi 
component.ts

```
updateMyDate(newDate) {
      this.myDate = newDate.target.value;
      console.log(this.myDate);
    }
```

que me arroja una fecha similar 
2019-05-10
esta fecha la quiero filtrar a un formato de mili segundos 
ejemplo: 1557985004000

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probarlo con:

```
(new Date(this.myDate)).getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo varias opciones que puedes usar, en angular puedes hacerlo desde el template con el **change** y el **ngModelChange**. Otra forma de hacerlo es con la forma reactiva. En este caso te mostraré desde el template, dado que es como lo estas haciendo:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  myDate;

  constructor() { }

  formatoMilisegundosNgModelChange(date: string) {
    console.log('ngModelChange');

    // Forma 1
    let fecha = Date.parse(date);
    console.log('Forma 1', new Date(this.myDate).getTime());

    // Forma 2
    fecha = new Date(this.myDate).getTime();
    console.log('Forma 2', fecha);
  }

  formatoMilisegundosChange(date: any) {
    console.log('change');
    // Forma 1
    let fecha = Date.parse(date);
    console.log('Forma 1', new Date(this.myDate).getTime());

    // Forma 2
    fecha = new Date(this.myDate).getTime();
    console.log('Forma 2', fecha);

    // Forma 3
    this.myDate = date.target.value;
    fecha = new Date(this.myDate).getTime();
    console.log('Forma 3', fecha);

    // Forma 4
    this.myDate = date.target.value;
    fecha = Date.parse(this.myDate);
    fecha = new Date(fecha).getTime();
    console.log('Forma 4', fecha);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" [(ngModel)]="myDate" (ngModelChange)="formatoMilisegundosNgModelChange($event);" (change)="formatoMilisegundosChange($event);">
```